# Cannot update to php 5.4 - AWS ec2

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services

I was having php5.3 and httpd2.2 on my instance. Now I need to upgrade to php 5.4.

I am following these instructions :

```
http://codingsteps.com/install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-php-apc-on-amazon-ec2-with-amazon-linux/
```

I have `sudo yum remove` all the conflicts and now the remaining two are:

```
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
```

But if I run for example :

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-44-86 ~]$ sudo yum install -y httpd24 php54
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-44-86 ~]$
```

EDIT :
I am trying to remove them :

```
sudo yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
```

But I get that :

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No Match for argument: httpd-tools-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
No Packages marked for removal
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove your old version of `httpd` prior to installing the new version.

```
yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64 httpd-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that but they cannot be removed. Check my edit, please

Comment: When you install, could you try skipping the `httpd` argument? Like this: `sudo yum install -y php54`

Comment: this didn;t work either, actually restarting apache, and exiting a couple of times the aws made it work - although I was running the exact same remove commands all the time.

Answer (score 7):

This might be a day late and a dollar short but this worked for me.

```
 sudo yum remove httpd* php*
 sudo yum install httpd24 php54
```

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=465912

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing PHP55 devel package.

I've solved uninstalling httpd and PHP again and installing with this command:

```
 sudo yum install -y httpd24 php55 php55-common php55-devel
```

Note that if you try to install httpd and php, and later php-devel, you get

```
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php55-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php55-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php55 conflicts with php-5.3.29-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
```

I hope this solution help you. I found my inspiration in: [PHP install on clean Amazon Linux AMI](https://serverfault.com/questions/631908/php-install-on-clean-amazon-linux-ami)

PD: Sorry about my english